# PHP MySQLi Query between two times from the query itself

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I basically having trouble finding out how I can get both "starttime" and "endtime" from the query I'm querying so it displays the data from the database between the times from the event.

MYSQL Query

```
$resultEvents = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events WHERE starttime >= (SELECT starttime FROM events) and endtime <= (SELECT endtime FROM events)");
```

PHP Display

```
<?php 
        while($events = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
                echo '<div id="eventnotification">';
                echo '<a href="./events/' . $events[1] . '"><div class="enc-' . $events[2] . '">';
                echo '<h5 class="notificationtitle">' . $events[3] . '</h5>';
                echo $events[4];
                echo '</div></a>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
         ?>
```

In the database table called `events`, there are:

- id
- eventname
- title
- description
- article
- creator
- starttime
- endtime

Selected data from the row are displayed on the page, but only between the starttime and enddate from that row is displayed, else, it won't be displayed.

Comment: What exactly is your startime and endtime?  Those subselects are grabbing all startimes and endtimes from your events table.  You need to pass the starttime and endtime into the query using PHP.

Comment: The starttime and endtime are in the TIMEDATE type.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  What IS the starttime and endtime?  How are you determining the exact times?

Comment: boojer is right. Your current statement will use a random row from events, and their start/endtime is used inside the where. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: It's so unclear what you want to achieve, but what I see you just need not where clause at all. Or? please clearly describe what you want to achieve

Comment: also you can't compare one field to multiple, I mean: your subqueries may return and im sure it will, more than one rows, so its not possible

Comment: `Selected data from the row are displayed on the page, but only between the starttime and enddate from that row is displayed, else, it won't be displayed.` can you re-formulate this phrase? maybe add content of table and desired html output

Comment: Right, Let's say I wanted the title and the description on a page. There are multiple events on and using the while, I can display the multiple events. Every event has an start/end time. Each event are displayed between the times that they have. If the current time is not between the start/end time, it will not be showed on the page.

Comment: @AlpineArctic ok, so answer from Rom is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `BETWEEN` would be more concise:

```
$resultEvents = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events WHERE NOW() BETWEEN starttime AND endtime");
```

Comment: This is correct, but the start/endtime '2013-12-12' and '2014-01-01' is inside the row table. The times are already set inside the row that I'm querying.

Comment: Well, the query as posted doesn't really make sense, it could've been reduced to `SELECT * FROM events`, I'm assuming you want to use the current time so I've updated my answer to be NOW() between starttime and endtime

Comment: @RobM. +1 Finally someone else who uses BETWEEN with dates and times!  (I've lost count of how many times someone has said to me, "that's not possible.")

Comment: In the MySQL Table, I have an starttime (Let's say 2013-12-12 23:30) and a endtime (2014-01-01 00:00). They are stored in the table that I'm querying. I'm basically wanting those times to be displayed between those times from a while loop. Possible?

Comment: @AlpineArctic what times should be displayed and where, give us example of output?

Comment: @AlpineArctic I don't understand this kind of english :(

Comment: @bishop It's simply the best way IMO to query for values between x and y :)

Comment: @RobM. No doubt! :)  Minds explode when ppl learn you can put INTERVAL in there to calculate temporal ranges on the fly!