# Subtracting php system time from a SQL datetime element

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying the list the remining time on an auction listing. Below is the SQL query to gather the item data. There is a created and end time in the database, stored as datetime. At the end of the foreach, I get the current time from the system.

What I want is the difference between them, so that I can display the remaining time on the auction. I have tried a few ways, but can't seem to solve it. How do I do it?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_auction_listing WHERE list_pk = $item LIMIT 1;");
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
               $sellerid = $row->seller_fk;

               $title = $row->title;

               $description = $row->description;

               $img_url = $row->image_url;
               $category = $row->category_fk;
               $starttime = $row->start_datetime;
               $endtime = $row->end_datetime;
               $startprice = $row->start_price;
               $reserve = $row->reserve_price;
               $buyprice = $row->bin_price;
               $visits = $row->visits;  
               $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            }
```

Note:

```
$remaining = $endtime->diff($now)->format("%m months, %d days, %H hours and %i minutes");
```

this line does not seem to work. It errors:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in controllers/listings.php on line 28

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20556191/ - if that's not what you're looking for, show us what you tried. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: I just added an edit which shows what I tried, thanks.

Comment: Try `timediff` instead of `diff` - might be the reason why. That, and/or a non-object; maybe a failed query.

Comment: There was a similar question posted earlier, this answer was submitted http://stackoverflow.com/a/25829875/ - again, many ways to do this. Have you Google'd for a bit? Checked Stack? I usually spend about an hour (min.) on Google myself, along with a fine cup of Espresso ;) *but that's just me.*

Comment: I generally peek around a bit. I tried editing my SQL query to `SELECT seller_fk, title, description, image_url, category_fk, remaining AS (TIMEDIFF(end_datetime,NOW()), start_price, reserve_price, bin_price, visits FROM tbl_auction_listing WHERE list_pk = 15 LIMIT 1;`, but that gives a syntax error.

Comment: Check out [`timediff`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php). Plus, did you try my suggestion(s)?

Comment: What syntax error exactly? Plus, you have a missing bracket `)` for `SELECT seller_fk, title, description, image_url, category_fk, remaining AS (TIMEDIFF(end_datetime,NOW()), start_price, reserve_price, bin_price, visits FROM tbl_auction_listing WHERE list_pk = 15 LIMIT 1;` - Try `SELECT seller_fk, title, description, image_url, category_fk, remaining AS (TIMEDIFF(end_datetime,NOW()), start_price, reserve_price, bin_price, visits FROM tbl_auction_listing WHERE list_pk = 15 LIMIT 1);`

Comment: not sure why the bracket was missing, but here was the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(TIMEDIFF(end_datetime,NOW()), start_price, reserve_price, bin_price, visits FRO' at line 1`

Comment: I'm not so hot with aliases, but try removing that bracket `(` and try `SELECT seller_fk, title, description, image_url, category_fk, remaining AS TIMEDIFF(end_datetime,NOW()), start_price, reserve_price, bin_price, visits FROM tbl_auction_listing WHERE list_pk = 15 LIMIT 1;` - if that still throws an error, consider going through some of the questions on Stack and Googling. I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: yep. still a fail. Its 1am here; I'll sleep on it and start fresh tomorrow. If I solve it I'll come back and post the answer.

Comment: It's 1am here too (headed off too), a fresh head in the morning usually does the trick. If I find anything more also, I'll let you know, *cheers.*

Answer (score 0):

im no php expert, but according to the docs there is [datetime diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and [datetime sub](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php).

in general if not possible to calculate directly, i tend to convert to unixtime seconds, calculate and convert back to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create DateTime objects in PHP from your query results.

```
$now        = new DateTime();
$endtime    = new DateTime($row->end_datetime);
$difference = $endtime->diff($now);
$remaining  = $difference->format("%m months, %d days, %H hours and %i minutes");
```

Also, you cannot chain methods in PHP like in other languages, such as JavaScript.

Comment: I am currently using EXACTLY as you posted: `$now        = new DateTime();
    $endtime    = new DateTime($row->end_datetime);
    $difference = $endtime->diff($now);
    $remaining  = $difference->format("%m months, %d days, %H hours and %i minutes");
   }` but I am still getting the error ` Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in /home/content/61/11420661/html/btcbidder.com/application/controllers/listings.php on line 29`. You can see the example at [http://btcbidder.com/listings/view/14

Comment: On the off chance that this is a php version error, I put in a request to upgrade with my host. I was running 5.3, which should have had this method available. I am upgrading to 5.4, so hopefully nothing breaks on my other sites in the process.

Comment: Upgraded to 5.4 and still the same error using the code you gave.

Comment: The code was just off the top of my head to give you a reference and a starting point. My apologies, I should have made that clear. Check out the PHP Docs on [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get more info.

Comment: Im not certain thats it.. I think the code is quite correct; its just that the system telling me that there is no diff method for DateTime objects..